# Multiple Child Forms behaving strangely

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2015, dock, mdichild

I have created a Form that dynamically loads buttons into a panel on the left hand side of an MDI Parent Form. Once loaded, a user can click one of the buttons, and a Child form will load into the right hand side, docked at the top and containing a datagridview with the results of some query. Each child form that is added sits directly below the previous one, due to the docking top property.

All this seems to work fine, however when more than one child forms is open the behaviour of the forms is unexpected. If I click on any child form other than the bottom form, it immediately moves its position to the bottom, rather than staying in place. Is there a way to deal with this - or is there something I am doing in my code that means this is happening - such as trying to dock a window?

My code is below.

```
Private Sub TableLookupForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim mySQLString As String = "Button SQL Query"

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    myVector.mySQLString = mySQLString


    For Each row In myVector.myIngresDataset.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim myBtn As New Button
        i = i + 1
        myBtn.Text = row("table_name")
        myBtn.Name = "Btn" & i
        myBtn.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        AddHandler myBtn.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(myBtn)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(myBtn, 0)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim myTableForm As New TableChildForm
        myTableForm.MdiParent = Me

        myTableForm.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        myTableForm.Tag = sender.text
        myTableForm.Text = sender.text

        Dim mySQLString As String = "Form SQL Query"

        myVector.mySQLString = mySQLString
        myTableForm.myTableData.DataSource = myVector.myIngresDataset.Tables(0)
        myTableForm.Show()

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: MDI child forms won't behave correctly when using that Dock property.  The Dock property was really meant for controls, which is why you won't see that property in the designer for forms.

Comment: When you click an MDI child it is automatically brought to front which also changes the docking order. It's much easier to create a method LayoutChildForms which you can call on resize / adding a new window / resizing a child, which will perform this simple logic for you without binding you to microsofts implementation